# Has Gothic 3 ever become kind of playable?

Tags: gothic-3

I just started playing Gothic again with the intention to play through the whole series in a flow.

I really loved the first 2 (and addon) because of its atmosphere.

I bought the 3rd part 1 year after its release and even a lot additional patches made this unplayable.

The game crashed every here and there. The lovely placed pickups from the previous games looked just like some one placed them with a 20x20 map editor tool.

really: I walked through deserts without any sign of life. And then just to see mirror like symmetric placed objects like trees in a plain so that some of them just almost where completely sunk in a mountain gain, while the others where just flying in the air. I walked along paths and saw wolves dropping from a spawn above my head down onto me.

So my question:

Did they kinda make to fix this

I never really finished playing Gothic 3 since it was disgusting and there was nothing about the atmosphere like in the previous parts.

And if not so, is there some point in the game where the previous named flaws get better? Or are the changes and bug fixes that minor that one will still face such odd things pretty often?

Comment: I heard you need a fan-made patch to play Gothic 3. I never played it, though.

Comment: I heared of that too. And thats what I'm more or less interested in. Will this make the game finaly playable and maybe even give it kinda flavour? Or better just stay away anyway?^^

Comment: I'm afraid this is very opinion-based and might get closed as such. FWIW, the [community patch team](http://www.g3cpt.eu/) fixed a lot of the gameplay-related issues (see the [manual (PDF)](http://s.g3cpt.de/manual/CP_1_7x_Manual.pdf)) and game-breaking bugs. However, I don't think they were able to restore the *feel* of the previous games (personal opinion right here).

Comment: @MrLemon: I understand this problem, thats why I tried to bring in a scale. askign about significant changes about area and crashes. Or just minor changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community patch made it playable. I played it a few years ago for about 30 hours and I didn't experience any significant bugs (crashes, broken quests, low framerate, weird balancing issues (e.g. boars killing literally everything)).

You won't however see any advancement regarding the general game balance (e.g. wolves remained a threat to my character, a dangerous enemy at level 1, still somewhat dangerous at level 30 with advanced armour) or any improvement to the actual content (e.g. nicer looking world, improved storyline and quests).

It really is just a patch to make the game playable, not to improve it. Make your own decisions from there.

However, I have to note, this information is from mid 2011, that's when I played it. According to the official site, the newest version is from 2010, so my post can be considered current.